# Mel Gibson movie where he picks the pocket of a guy on the street

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember seeing a few scenes of this movie and would like to figure out the name:

- So the main character was probably Mel Gibson or someone very similar.
- The story was set around 90s in a bigger city...as usual probably New York
- Main character was walking down the street and intentionally bumped into another man, pick-pocketing his wallet...later on I think he was in some hotel room paying with his credit card.
- There was also a generic action scene, not sure how it went, but it had something to do with classic black american muscle car (something like a Mustang, Dodge, Impala …).

Sorry for the vague description, but the actor is famous so someone might recognize the movie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to identify [Payback from 1999](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120784/) which did star Mel Gibson. It does feature a scene where his picks the pocket of a guy who vaguely resembles himself and uses his card to buy stuff. He's actually in a restaurant when he tries to pay with the stolen card.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payback_%281999_film%29):

> In a seedy basement, Porter (**Mel Gibson**) lies severely wounded with two gunshot wounds in his back. A whiskey-drinking surgeon removes the bullets and Porter spends months healing.
>
> **Stealing a credit card to acquire a new suit, food and a gun,** Porter begins tracking down Val Resnick (Gregg Henry), his former partner, and Lynn (Deborah Unger), his ex-wife, both of whom betrayed Porter following a $140,000 heist from the Chinese triads. After leaving Porter for dead, Val rejoined the Outfit, a powerful criminal organization, using $130,000 of the heist money to repay an outstanding debt. Porter is intent on reclaiming his $70,000 cut.

(*Payback* has a tag on this site: [payback](/questions/tagged/payback).)

Comment: That looks like it,there is even that black car...tnx